# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lioutil in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu

I want to do makefile as the following, but I received this error:

gcc frparse.o frtags.o frscan.o frinit.o frstop.o frfoot.o frio.o -L/usr/local/image/lib/sgi -lioutil -lutil -o frparse

**/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lioutil**

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'frparse' failed
make: *** [frparse] Error 1

I would appreciate it if you guide me.

```
IMLIB   = /usr/local/image/lib/sgi
LLIBS   = -lioutil -lutil

it: frparse frcheck pgrep
OBJ = frparse.o frtags.o frscan.o frinit.o frstop.o frfoot.o frio.o


frparse.o: Makefile frparse.h frio.h frproto.h frstop.h frparse.c
frinit.o: Makefile frparse.h frproto.h frinit.c
frscan.o: Makefile frio.h frstop.h frscan.c
frfoot.o: Makefile frparse.h frproto.h frstop.h frfoot.c
frtags.o: Makefile frparse.h frio.h frproto.h frstop.h frtags.c
frstop.o: Makefile frstop.h frstop.c
frio.o: Makefile frio.c

frparse: $(OBJ)
        gcc $(OBJ) -L$(IMLIB) $(LLIBS) -o $@


frcheck: frcheck.o
        gcc frcheck.o -L$(IMLIB) $(LLIBS) -o $@

pgrep: pgrep.o
        gcc pgrep.o -L$(IMLIB) $(LLIBS) -o $@

.c.o:
#   cc -c -O2 -mips2 $<
        gcc -c -g $<
```

Comment: Do you have a library `libioutil.a` somewhere? Where? Please [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: It appears that `libioutil.a` (or `.so`, or …) is not present where the loader can find it.  Check where the library is; endure the loader is looking in the correct place.

Answer (score 2):

regarding:

```
.c.o:
#   cc -c -O2 -mips2 $< 
    gcc -c -g $<
```

The comment `#` must ALSO be indented via a `<tab>`  otherwise the recipe never performs the third line

Also, the syntax is a bit obsolete suggest:

```
%.o:%.c
```

for the first line of the recipe

However, regarding your question:

Is there actually a library file named `libioutil.so` in the directory:

```
/usr/local/image/lib/sgi
```

Comment: Pattern rules are a GNUism, so until GNU finishes taking over the world, the suffix rule syntax is **not** obsolete.  POSIX, for its part, [says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/make.html) "The interpretation of targets containing the characters '%' and '"' is implementation-defined."  Suffix rules (vs. pattern rules) are the way to go for portability, including, notably, in Autotools-based projects, despite the Autotools themselves being a GNU project.